# flutter navigator in alert box not working

Tags: flutter, alert, navigator

in an edit page, once an edit is done I am showing an alert with Ok button. Once Okay button clicked, i wan to move to the previous screen. FOllowing is my alert box code

```
Future<Null> _showDoneDialog() async {
    return showDialog<Null>(
      context: context,
      //barrierDismissible: true,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                        child: Text(
                          "Profile has been edited successfully",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontFamily: 'Oswald',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        )),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: header,
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))),
                                child: Text(
                                  "OK",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

How to call the previous screen from alertbox -> Navigator.of(context).pop();

Comment: When you click the "OK" button the dialog closes itself ?

Comment: Yes, the alert box gets closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showDialog` uses the Navigator to show. So if your navigator stack is

Screen1>Screen2

when you show your dialog it becomes

Screen1>Screen2>FlutterDialog

And... when you "pop" the navigator, it pops the last route, in this case, it's moving to the previous screen `Screen2`

What i would suggest is waiting for the dialog to pop, then "pop" again (To go to Screen 1)

You can do this in a simple manner.Just wait for the dialog to close itself

```
void _showDoneDialog() async {
    await showDialog<Null>(
      context: context,
      //barrierDismissible: true,
      builder: (BuildContext dialogContext) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Center(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                        child: Text(
                          "Profile has been edited successfully",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              fontSize: 14,
                              fontFamily: 'Oswald',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                        )),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                Navigator.of(dialogContext).pop();
                              });
                            },
                            child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: header,
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(100))),
                                child: Text(
                                  "OK",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                  ),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );


    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
```